# JQuery EasyUi Datagrid, Multiple extensions in one datagrid

Tags: jquery, datagrid, detailview, jquery-easyui

Hello has any of you tried using multiple extensions in data-grid? 
In my case I'm trying to use these extensions:

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid27_demo.html
and:
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid21_demo.html

In one data-grid table.

I already looked for this kind of setup: http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid21_demo.html, but it seems that do not have any demos on how it do it.